# Can I build Blender source code using CLion?

Tags: versions, compile, source-code

I'm pretty new in Blender coding. I'm only  did some small things using python scripting so far. I'm facing a problem where I wish to see more about the UI components of Blender (panels, icon viewers, etc) in C++ but I don't know how to build it. I would like to try CLion, but I can't find any tutorials.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: You can use CLion as IDE, although the actual building would be done via [cmake and make](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender). I'd recommend VSCode over CLion though and it already has a [tutorial in the wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Developer_Intro/Environment/Portable_CMake_VSCode).

Comment: Thank you @RobertGützkow, while trying do the steps I'm facing the problem

`make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 2`
after building the project in build_linux folder. I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: I just found it. the .vscode folder with the workspace settings should be blaced inside the 'build_linux' folder, but I started the project with the blender-git folder and the build_linux folder in the same project. @RobertGützkow Thank you anyway. If you'd like to post as an answer I'll be glad to vode as best answer.

Comment: Have you make it work with CLion? Is it too much of hassle?

Answer (score 0):

I am a novice to C, but after a week-long series of attempts I would not recommend it.

Given how the project is set-up for Windows (VS required), it is likely you will end up using MS's compilator, output of which is not friendly with CLion's default debugger GDB, [allegedly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26846852/224239).